# Unexplained crushed log of ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I received a lot of SIGSEGV exceptions from Tencent bugly (a bug monitoring platform), but I can't reproduce it when I debug online. I think this is the flashback caused by the application going into the background and then entering the foreground, but this is just my opinion, I hope someone can help.

So I hope someone has the same problem and can help me understand why my application crashes.

From reading the crash report below, does anyone have any suggestions why my app crashes?

```
#0 Thread
0 libsystem_c.dylib   fclose + 40
1 libsystem_c.dylib   fclose + 36
2 Union               FileLogger::~FileLogger() + 28
3 libsystem_c.dylib   __cxa_finalize_ranges + 384
4 libsystem_c.dylib   exit + 24
5 UIKit               +[_UIAlertManager hideAlertsForTermination]
6 UIKit               ___102-[UIApplication _handleApplicationDeactivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.2093 + 792
7 UIKit               __runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 292
8 UIKit               __cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 528
9 UIKit               __afterCACommitHandler + 132
10 CoreFoundation     ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
11 CoreFoundation     ___CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
12 CoreFoundation     ___CFRunLoopRun + 956
13 CoreFoundation     CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
14 GraphicsServices   GSEventRunModal + 100
15 UIKit              UIApplicationMain + 208
16 Union              main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
17 libdyld.dylib      _start + 4

#1 Thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x00000001858bddbc __workq_kernreturn
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859cf144 _pthread_wqthread

#2 Thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x00000001858bddbc __workq_kernreturn
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859cf144 _pthread_wqthread

#3 Thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x00000001858bd150 __psynch_cvwait
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d6fd0 __pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81
2 Union                     0x00000001031a2508 CNEvent::Wait(int)
3 Union                     0x0000000103109f18 CNELogRecordThread::Run(void*)
4 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d032c __pthread_body
5 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d01f8 __pthread_body

#4 com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x000000018589cbc4 mach_msg_trap
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x000000018589ca3c mach_msg
2 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185d4bce4 ___CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185d498b0 ___CFRunLoopRun
4 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185c6a2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5 Foundation                0x00000001866926e4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]
6 Foundation                0x00000001866b1afc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]
7 UIKit                     0x000000018fd6202c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain]
8 Foundation                0x0000000186793860 ___NSThread__start__
9 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d032c __pthread_body
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00000001859d01f8 __pthread_body

#5 Thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x00000001858bddbc __workq_kernreturn
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859cefb0 _pthread_wqthread

#6 com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x000000018589cbc4 mach_msg_trap
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x000000018589ca3c mach_msg
2 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185d4bce4 ___CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185d498b0 ___CFRunLoopRun
4 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185c6a2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5 CFNetwork                 0x00000001863d3b40 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:]
6 Foundation                0x0000000186793860 ___NSThread__start__
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d032c __pthread_body
8 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d01f8 __pthread_body

#7 com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x000000018589cbc4 mach_msg_trap
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x000000018589ca3c mach_msg
2 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185d4bce4 ___CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185d498b0 ___CFRunLoopRun
4 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185c6a2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185cb912c CFRunLoopRun
6 CoreMotion                0x000000018b04e088 CLStartStopAdvertisingBeacon
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d032c __pthread_body
8 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d01f8 __pthread_body

#8 Thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x00000001858bd150 __psynch_cvwait
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d6fd0 __pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81
2 Union                     0x0000000102a67884 _baidu_vi::CVEvent::Wait(unsigned int)
3 Union                     0x0000000102a67d8c _baidu_vi::CVThreadEvent::Wait()
4 Union                     0x0000000102a66724 _baidu_vi::CVSocketMan::SocketThreadProc(void*)
5 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d032c __pthread_body
6 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d01f8 __pthread_body

#9 AFNetworking
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x000000018589cbc4 mach_msg_trap
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x000000018589ca3c mach_msg
2 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185d4bce4 ___CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185d498b0 ___CFRunLoopRun
4 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185c6a2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5 Foundation                0x00000001866926e4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]
6 Foundation                0x00000001866e462c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run]
7 Union                     0x00000001037fe074 +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:164)
8 Foundation                0x0000000186793860 ___NSThread__start__
9 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d032c __pthread_body
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00000001859d01f8 __pthread_body

#10 Thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x000000018589cbc4 mach_msg_trap
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x000000018589ca3c mach_msg
2 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185d4bce4 ___CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185d498b0 ___CFRunLoopRun
4 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185c6a2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5 Union                     0x00000001022b84a0 +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:4800)
6 Foundation                0x0000000186793860 ___NSThread__start__
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d032c __pthread_body
8 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d01f8 __pthread_body

#11 com.apple.CFSocket.private
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x00000001858bd570 __select
1 CoreFoundation            0x0000000185d5421c ___CFSocketManager
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d032c __pthread_body
3 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859d01f8 __pthread_body

#12 Thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x00000001858bddbc __workq_kernreturn
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859cf144 _pthread_wqthread

#13 Thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x00000001858bddbc __workq_kernreturn
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859cf144 _pthread_wqthread

#14 Thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x00000001858bddbc __workq_kernreturn
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859cefb0 _pthread_wqthread

#15 Thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x00000001858bddbc __workq_kernreturn
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859cf144 _pthread_wqthread
```

Here is the page tracking information

```
06-30 18:32:43.888 [ UICompatibilityInputViewController ] WillAppear
106-30 18:32:44.755 UIApplication DidEnterBackground
206-30 18:32:44.781 [ UICompatibilityInputViewController ] WillAppear
306-30 18:32:44.931 [ UICompatibilityInputViewController ] WillAppear
406-30 18:33:46.236 UIApplication WillEnterForeground
506-30 18:33:46.255 [ UICompatibilityInputViewController ] WillAppear
606-30 18:33:47.350 UIApplication DidBecomeActive
706-30 18:33:50.010 [ ResourDetailOrderController 工单详情 ] WillAppear
806-30 18:33:52.211 [ UIApplicationRotationFollowingController ] WillAppear
906-30 18:33:52.249 [ UIAlertController 系统提示 ] WillAppear
1006-30 18:33:54.435 [ ReplyListViewController 回单 ] WillAppear
1106-30 18:34:06.095 [ TerminalScanCodeController 终端扫码 ] WillAppear
1206-30 18:34:13.924 [ MMScanViewController 二维码 ] WillAppear
1306-30 18:34:19.460 [ TerminalScanCodeController 终端扫码 ] WillAppear
1406-30 18:34:20.208 [ UIAlertController 确定要提交? ] WillAppear
1506-30 18:34:21.723 [ ReplyListViewController 回单 ] WillAppear
1606-30 18:34:23.322 [ ResourDetailOrderController 工单详情 ] WillAppear
1706-30 18:34:39.841 [ WorkformKTQueryViewController 开通工单 ] WillAppear
1806-30 18:34:49.848 UIApplication WillResignActive
1906-30 18:34:50.643 UIApplication DidEnterBackground
2006-30 18:34:50.657 UIApplication WillTerminate
```

Some other information

```
Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
1 x0:000000000000000000 x1:0x0000000190b477c4 x2:000000000000000000 x3:0x0000000190c2f2c0
2 x4:000000000000000000 x5:0x0000000000000010 x6:000000000000000000 x7:0x0000000000000160
3 x8:0x000000004f4e4345 x9:0x000000010090efb8 x10:0x00055e0000055f03 x11:000000000000000000
4 x12:0x00055f0000055f00 x13:0x0000000000055f00 x14:0x0000000000000001 x15:0x0000000000000881
5 x16:0x0000000190b06dbc x17:000000000000000000 x18:000000000000000000 x19:0x0000206800000000
6 x20:0x00000001b7ec66f0 x21:0x00000001b7ec7000 x22:0x0000000103826800 x23:000000000000000000
7 x24:0x0000000000000008 x25:0x00000001b7ec7000 x26:0x0000000000000018 x27:0x0000000000000017
8 x28:0x0000000000000002 fp:0x000000016fdba6f0 lr:0x0000000190b06de0 sp:0x000000016fdba6e0
9 pc:0x0000000190b06de4 cpsr:0x0000000020000000
10 Binary Infos:
11 App UUID: 155BFA4F47CA30CB91D18CDA865ED418
12 App base addr: 0x0000000100044000
13 App Arch: arm64
14 Cpu Arch: arm64
15 System Binary infos:
16 Union: arm64;155bfa4f47ca30cb91d18cda865ed418;0x0000000100044000
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib: arm64;a9496f189b713c25962a892a4b055b2b;0x0000000190cae000
18 libsystem_kernel.dylib: arm64;98ea0e581e203a67a8436a5bbba44e35;0x0000000190bca000
19 libdyld.dylib: arm64;e514c9464eed3be5943a2c61d9241fad;0x0000000190ad5000
20 libsystem_c.dylib: arm64;4fada8fe23433d16a6bfd9ef0cc6ee2b;0x0000000190afc000
21 CoreFoundation: arm64;719044f95fe23ee0ab14504def42b100;0x0000000191ac2000
22 Foundation: arm64;b301584673973341a35216f9c24a4a8b;0x00000001925d9000
23 CFNetwork: arm64;90d5c0c0c2813113ada33291569dd779;0x00000001921f6000
24 GraphicsServices: arm64;b5749f3fa6f13ce689683db33f23256c;0x0000000193529000
25 CoreMotion: arm64;22cacab0e3d633e7922447665e13c625;0x0000000198bb5000
26 UIKit: arm64;314063bdf85f321d88d6e24a0de464a2;0x0000000197d11000
```

Comment: have you written hideAlertsForTermination this function then check there some issue in that code. or have you call any method using timer. if possible post code so we can understand your code issue

Comment: I searched this function hideAlertsForTermination globally, and did not find it defined @PravinTate

Comment: Are you running any processes while the app is in the background?

Comment: @AshleyMills I revised some information again. Can you see it for me? thanks